# If you accept an answer, unaccept it, and then accept it again, will the person get two notifications?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Just wondering: sometimes I do that tentatively but then change my mind (for a short while).

Comment: As far as I know you don't get a notification when someone accepts your answer. You just get more reputation.

Comment: ... and get less if the answer is unaccepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There aren't notifications for accepted answers.
The users will notice that, when you accept their answer, their reputation is increased, and it is decreased when you deselect their answer as accepted. If they watch the tab showing their reputation, they will notice one of their answer has been accepted as they see a +15, when you accept the answer.

Comment: Is it just me or does it actually sound fun to play with someone's reputation like that? lol

Answer (score 1):

A user is not notified when his/her answer is accepted or unaccepted, so they will not be notified if you change the accepted answer.